# iOS 9 : Extension crashing on reaching 5mb memory usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios9

I developed a network extension and it crashes as soon as its memory reach 5MB mark.After googling I found in iOS 9 memory limit for extensions is 5MB and in iOS 10 and above have 15MB.My extension works well on iOS 11 device so these stats seem true to myself.Although I could not find any official documentation for memory limit.

I was just wondering that is there a way I can run part of my code on app's behalf instead of extension's behalf and then later fetch data from app.Just a random thought!!

Also if there is any way to decrease memory usage of extensions please share your thoughts(random ones as welcome too) as well.

Added part of code that seems most suspicious to myself.

```
CFErrorRef err = NULL;
        NSLog(@"URL to be examined is: %s",url);
        NSURL* URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:url]];
        NSString* str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:pacData];
        NSArray* proxies = CFBridgingRelease(CFNetworkCopyProxiesForAutoConfigurationScript((__bridge CFStringRef)str, (__bridge CFURLRef)URL, &err));
        NSLog(@"Proxies Found are: %s",url);
        if(err || !proxies || [proxies count] < 1){
            NSError* nserr = CFBridgingRelease(err);
            NSLog(@"pac err:%@",nserr.debugDescription);
            nserr = nil;
        }else{
            NSDictionary* settings = [proxies objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString* temp = [settings objectForKey:(NSString*)kCFProxyHostNameKey];
            NSNumber* port = [settings objectForKey:(NSString*)kCFProxyPortNumberKey];
            if(temp){
                NSLog(@"pac success:%@",temp);
                returnvalue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PROXY %@:%d;",temp,port.intValue];
//                return (char*)temp.UTF8String;
            }
            settings = nil;
            temp = nil;
            port = nil;
        }
        URL = nil;
        str = nil;
        proxies = nil;
```

Comment: Are you willing to share this extension? Maybe there is a way to reduce the memory usage.

Comment: @LloydKeijzer Unfortunately I can't share whole extension.I will share most suspicious part of code with you.

Comment: @DesertRose did you fix the problem??

Comment: @m1sh0 Apple admitted that there are memory leaks in their code.Dont know when they will fix it.